# unambiguous context-free languages and complementation

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties, ambiguity

I was considering the following two natural questions about the relationship between unambiguity and complementation for the class of context-free languages:

1. Is the complement of an unambiguous context-free language also a context-free language?
2. If a language is context-free, and its complement is context-free as well (i.e., a so-called *strongly context-free language*), is it the case that the language is unambiguous context-free?

The first question above is motivated by the fact that it holds for deterministic context-free languages, which are a strict subclass of the unambiguous context-free languages.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. The two here don't seem to be related at all are better asked separately.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Both questions turn out to have negative answers, as shown in [this][1] article.
In particular, the authors construct

1. An unambiguous context-free language whose complement is not context-free.
2. An inherently ambiguous (i.e., non-unambiguous) context-free language whose complement is context-free.

Consequently, there is no relationship between the notion of unambiguity for context-free languages and the complementation operation.

[1] [The Independence of Inherent Ambiguity From Complementedness Among Context-Free Languages"](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/321356.321366) by Hibbard and Ullian, JACM, Volume 13 Issue 4, Oct. 1966, Pages 588-593
 https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=321356.321366